# В чем смысловая разница между следующими предложениями?

Tags: синтаксис

1. Вспоминаю: внезапно, проснувшись около полуночи, вскочил я с постели.
2. Вспоминаю: внезапно проснувшись около полуночи, вскочил я с постели.
3. Вспоминаю: внезапно проснувшись, около полуночи вскочил я с постели.
4. Вспоминаю внезапно: проснувшись около полуночи, вскочил я с постели.
5. Вспоминаю внезапно: проснувшись, около полуночи вскочил я с постели.
6. Вспоминаю внезапно, проснувшись: около полуночи вскочил я с постели.
7. Вспоминаю внезапно, проснувшись около полуночи: вскочил я с постели.
8. Вспоминаю, внезапно проснувшись  около полуночи: вскочил я с постели.

Во втором предложении мысль ясна: наречие "внезапно" непосредственно относится к глаголу. Но не понятно, к чему относится обособленное наречие "внезапно" в первом предложении и есть ли смысловая разница между первым и вторым предложением?

В третьем предложении, думаю, говорится о том, что автор внезапно проснулся и только к полуночи вскочил с постели.
В четвертом и  пятом предложении с наречием все ясно: оно входит в главное предложение. Т. е. автор говорит о том, что он именно вспомнил внезапно. Но мысль не ясна с придаточными. В четвертом говорится о том, что автор проснулся около полуночи и вскочил с постели. 
Разница между пятым и третьим предложением в том, что в третьем автор вспоминает, как он внезапно проснулся около полуночи, а в пятом акцент на том, что именно он вспомнил внезапно.

А в чем разница между последними двумя, и насколько правильно я поняла смысл?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Здесь вариации того, к чему относятся "внезапно" и "около полуночи": вспомнил, вскочил или проснулся.

1. Я проснулся около полуночи. Внезапно вскочил с постели.
2. Около полуночи я внезапно проснулся. Вскочил с постели.
3. Я внезапно проснулся. Около полуночи вскочил с постели.
4. Я внезапно кое-что вспомнил. Около полуночи я проснулся и вскочил с постели.
5. Я внезапно кое-что вспомнил. Я проснулся, а около полуночи вскочил с постели.
6. Я проснулся и внезапно кое-что вспомнил. Оказывается, около полуночи я вскочил с постели.
7. Около полуночи я проснулся и внезапно вспомнил, что вскочил с постели.
8. Около полуночи я внезапно проснулся; вспомнил, что вскочил с постели.

Comment: В 7-м у Вас повторение "я", по-моему, излишне, Александр.

Comment: Да, спасибо (двойное употребление "я" здесь возможно, но в исходном тексте одно "я"),

Comment: Думаю, в седьмом наоборот: проснулся около полуночи и внезапно вспомнил, что вскочил я с постели. Об этом говорит то, что наречие ''внезапно'' отделено запятой. А ваш 7-й вариант соответствует моему восьмому. Кажется, разобралась.

Comment: Это из-за отсутствия запятой в исходной версии седьмого - я мысленно поставил её после первого слова. Сейчас изменю.

Answer (score 2):

> Во втором предложении мысль ясна: наречие "внезапно" непосредственно
>   относится к глаголу.

К глаголу *внезапно* относится как раз в первом, а не во втором предложении. А во втором оно относится к деепричастию *проснувшись.* И на мой взгляд, *внезапно* в первом предложении лучше переставить в конец.
Насчёт третьего согласен.

> В третьем предложении, думаю, говорится о том, что автор внезапно
>   проснулся и только к полуночи вскочил с постели... Разница между пятым
>   и третьим предложением в том, что в третьем автор вспоминает, как он
>   внезапно проснулся около полуночи...

А тут Вы сама себе противоречите насчёт третьего. Вначале Вы написали правильно, что автор проснулся (до полуночи) и к полуночи вскочил с постели (не известно, сколько прошло). В пятом то же самое: он вскочил с постели около полуночи, а проснулся раньше. Насчёт того, к чему относится *внезапно*, у Вас всё правильно.

Шестое предложение я бы переделал: "Проснувшись, я внезапно вспомнил, как около полуночи вскочил с постели" . Смысл, надеюсь, Вы поняли.

Седьмое вообще неправильное по знакам препинания — не выделен деепричастный оборот. Восьмое тоже очень странное по смыслу, который я бы передал так: "Внезапно проснувшись около полуночи, я вспомнил, как вскочил с постели (неизвестно когда и чем это примечательно). С двоеточием и таким концом выглядит очень странно.

Comment: Да, конечно. Когда писала, сбилась с мысли. Во втором предложении наречие ''внезапно'' относится к деепричастию. Это я и хотела сказать. А вот насчет первого Вы очень помогли мне. Там оно действительно относится к глаголу, следовало бы догадаться.

Comment: В пятом тоже сбилась с мысли. Исправлю в вопросе.

Comment: Артем, в седьмом не хватало запятой, добавила. В остальном - все верно. Это вопрос из программы ''Сила слова" , телеканал "Санкт-Петербург''. Там требовалось расставить знаки препинания.

Comment: Ничего себе, такой канал даже есть! Но у меня всё равно телевизора нету.)))

Comment: Большое спасибо за помощь! К сожалению, не смогу отдать голос за ваш ответ. Не хватает репутации.

Comment: Артем, я смотрел эту программу. Если хотите, могу выслать ссылку. В Ютубе пока этой передачи нет.

Comment: Если совсем не сложно, киньте, Серж. Всё смотреть точно не буду, если не станет вдруг очень интересно, а чуть гляну.

Comment: Артем, а куда скинуть?

Comment: Я думал, вы сюда выложите. Можете ещё на artyomlugovoy@gmail.com, если не сюда. Спасибо!